# Dynamically add checkBoxPreference to PreferenceFragment

Tags: android

I need to display a directory listing of files and folders that I get of an API. Once a user clicks on one of the directories I look for its sub directories and list them under the parent one just to the right, and so it goes on. **Not Sure what the best way is for this?**

I made a settings view and Have a "Directories" setting. Once you click on it I need to load the sub directories in the PreferenceScreen. And the user must be able to drill down into the sub directories and select the ones he wants with something like a **checkBoxPreference**

So In the end I can make up a list of Checked Directories.

**MY IDEAS**

1. Show folders, once user clicks on a folder, slide the sub folders into view, and so on.
2. Show folders, once user clicks on a folder, show the subfolders just below the parent folder, moving the children little to the right.
3. Show the folders that was selected as **checkBoxPreferences**, and have a button to start a new view that the user selects the folders from

I am really new to Android dev and not sure how I would implement any of these?

Can you please direct my in some direction so I may try it? Im not asking for a code example, just a logical explanation of some possible methods or ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very abstract, so I can't give you a concrete answer.

I can provide some guidance and examples though.

Example of dynamically adding a preference (replace EditTextPreference with CheckboxPreference) and get a list of files before that:

**SettingsActivity** (extends PreferenceActivity)

```
private void setHomeDirectoryPreference(String home_dir)
{
    final EditTextPreference etp = new EditTextPreference(this);

    etp.setKey("home_directory");
    etp.setTitle("Home directory");
    //...
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    ((PreferenceScreen) findPreference("initial_preference")).addPreference(etp);
}
```

Listing a file subfiles:

```
file.listFiles();
```

Also, you may need to often check whether the underlying file exists:

```
f.exists();
```

> Once you click on it I need to load the sub directories in the
>   PreferenceScreen

I'd personaly do it using a PreferenceDialog and a ListView:

Example of a DialogPreference:

```
public class HiddenFilesDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public static Context ctx;

    public HiddenFilesDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.ctx = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();

        View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_view, null);

        ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        File[] hidden_files = HiddenFileHandler.getAllHiddenFilesAsFiles();

        HiddenFilesListAdapter adapter = new HiddenFilesListAdapter(ctx, hidden_files);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return vw;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        persistBoolean(positiveResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        super.onClick(dialog, which);

        Log.v("which", Integer.toString(which));

        if(which == -1) { //Clear all
            HiddenFileHandler hfh = new HiddenFileHandler(ctx);

            hfh.clearHiddenFiles();
        }
    }

}
```

Then, in your dialog, you can set onClickListeners() to replace the dialog content, etc.

Start with concrete implementation and then return with more specific questions.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and take it from there.

Comment: Im still figuring out, not sure about this part LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();

Comment: Im not sure how the HiddenFilesListAdapter class will look and return.